# how to pass variables from controller to model in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

## controller:

```
public function getimagesprojects()
{
    $param2 = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $param3 = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $data   = $this->Admin_db->getimages($param2, $param3);
    foreach ($data as $images) {
        return $images;
    }
}
```

here I pass two variables from ajax method to the above controller.
Then I call `getimages` method of model by passing two variables but values are not passing to model.

model:

```
function getimages($vendor_id, $vendor_pid)
{
    echo $vendor_id;
    echo $vendor_pid;
    $images = array();
    $res    = $this->db->query("SELECT project_gallery FROM projects where vendor_id='$vendor_id' and id='$vendor_pid';");
    foreach ($res->result_array() as $row) {
        $images[] = $row;
    }
    return $images;
}
```

In the above model I am trying to print values which are passed but not prited.
please help me.

Comment: Are you able to get values in "getimagesprojects" function. Try echo $param2 = $this->uri->segment(4); and other and die; Are you able to get this values.

Comment: yes. I am getting values into $param1,$param2.i just check it by echo.

Comment: In the model,I echo the values $vendor_id and $vendor_pid to check whether values are passed or not.but values are not printed.then query is also not going to successful.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` images instead of returning.And in model `return $res->result_array()`.The `result_array()` returns the result in `array` format.

**Controller:**

```
public function getimagesprojects()

{

 $param2 = $this->uri->segment(4);

$param3 =$this->uri->segment(5);
$this->load->model('Admin_db');
$data=$this->Admin_db->getimages($param2,$param3);
foreach($data as $images)

  {

  echo $images;//echo here

  }
}
```

**Model:**

```
function getimages($vendor_id, $vendor_pid)
{
    echo $vendor_id;
    echo $vendor_pid;
    $images = array();
    $res    = $this->db->query("SELECT project_gallery FROM projects where vendor_id='$vendor_id' and id='$vendor_pid'");
   return $res->result_array();//just return result in aray format
}
```

Comment: In the model,I echo the values $vendor_id and $vendor_pid to check whether values are passed or not.but values are not printed.then query is also not going to successful.Then array retuned will be empty.so how to pass variables to model from controller

Comment: dont forget to load model first in conteoller.

Comment: I call the model properly

Comment: did you get value of `$param2` and `$param3 ` properly.

Comment: i get $param2 and $param3 values properly

Comment: when i echo the values of  $param2  and $param3 before       $data=$this->Admin_db->getimages($param2,$param3); are printed. But after this line values are not printed.What might me the problem .Is there any problem in model or controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you pass the variable to the model only to echo them from there, model shouldn't be printing anyway, do the printing in the controller (or better still, in the view). Then you iterate the result_array only to recreate the exact same array under the name $images, that's unnecessary. I'm not sure if your query was working correctly, but I made a change to use the Codeigniter functions as they are a little cleaner and are more secure.

Controller:

```
public function getimagesprojects()
{
    $param2 = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $param3 = $this->uri->segment(5);
    echo $param2;
    echo $param3;
    $data   = $this->Admin_db->getimages($param2, $param3);
    foreach ($data as $images) {
        echo $images;
    }
}
```

model:

```
function getimages($vendor_id, $vendor_pid)
{

    $images = array();
    $this->db->where('vendor_id', $vendor_id);
    $this->db->where('id', $vendor_pid);
    $res = $this->db->get('project_gallery');

    return $res->result_array();
}
```